# Ext6 /Sencha Build Error with Ext.window.Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

im trying to build the sample app from this side :
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/login_app.html

Using sencha app watch and netbeans for deleopment.

Instead of using this method :
sencha -sdk /path/to/ExtSDK generate app **-classic** TutorialApp ./TutorialApp

I used this (because I need to create a App for mobile devices):

sencha -sdk /path/to/ExtSDK generate app **-modern** TutorialApp ./TutorialApp

I can test the default app and it works nice. But as soon as i add this line from the Tutorial:

```
Ext.define('TutorialApp.view.login.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
xtype: 'login'
```

});

Sencha watch is throwing a " Unknown defintions  for dependecy : Ext.window.Window

Ideas?

Comment: The modern toolkit does not have a `Ext.window.Window` class.

Comment: ok wow good to know. So ill just use panels instead.

Comment: As @Hannes Dernbrant stated below, use Ext.Dialog because the modern framework does not have Ext.window.Window. 

I know "panels" will not work in classic as a window so I would also assume modern is not going to open a "panel" as a dialog..

Answer (score -1):

[Ext.Dialog](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Dialog.html) with closable: true is pretty close the classic toolkit's Ext.window.Window. It can for instance hold a formpanel item.